# WordPress Local Install Error (XAMPP) - Page 2 is Blank

Tags: wordpress, installation, xampp, localserver

I'm trying to install WordPress for local use with XAMPP. I started off by installing and unzipping both the XAMPP and WordPress folders. I placed the XAMPP folder in my C:/ drive and my WordPress folder within the "htdocs" folder. After that, I made a new "config" file for my local server based on the "config-sample" file.

Here's where things get tricky: when I try to use the "install.php" file, I am brought to a screen that asks for credentials. I give it some generic credentials and then I submit it in order to install WordPress. However, when I submit the form, the loaded page is completely blank and the URL appears as "localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php?step=2".

When I go into the database, it shows me that WordPress created all of the necessary tables, but didn't create any log-in credentials for me. I was doing some research and there were a couple pages that mentioned the need for increased PHP RAM, but I'm unsure of how to increase the RAM for local use or if it's even a problem. If anyone had an error like this happen to them, I would really appreciate some feedback as to what could be causing this problem.

Comment: Have you read this one: http://www.nkjlive.com/2008/11/wordpress-blank-screen-of-death/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem, with an almost blank screen on step-2 passage.
Adding in `wp-config.php` these lines solved everything:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '128M');

set_time_limit(60);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Wordpress 4.0 from a zip file on XAMPP 1.8.3 on my Win7-32bit PC.

Setting up the DB and all, I got the same "blank screen" at the step 2.
So, I went in to phpMyAdmin, and edited the "wp_users" table on my entry. I modified the user_login and the user_password (using an MD5 converter). Saved the entry and got into the localhost url for wordpress. Got into the log in, and everything seems to be working without any issues.

As a note: I installed a fresh/clean install so there were no custom themes nor plugins.

Hope that helps.